# Capture second quoted string without trailing quote/delimiter

Tags: regex

New regex learner here, I have a string that is reliably two quoted strings separated by a colon, like:

```
"foo": "bar"
```

I am trying to extract just `"bar"` without the quotes

I've come up with this:

```
\:([^"]*"){2}
```

which gives me: `bar"` in the second match, but I am struggling to sort out a way to eliminate the trailing quote.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of regex are you using? (i.e. -- what language?)

Comment: Windows/Powershell - trincot's answer below worked in my case. thanks for replying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use look-ahead to verify that the double quote that is following is also the last character in the input:

[`[^"]*(?="$)`](https://regex101.com/r/EDVdRC/1)

Comment: This did it, and is instructive , thank you! That website is a keeper, thx

Answer (score 2):

Your best approach depends on the flavor of regex you are using. There are some tricks that can allow you to match *only* the piece you want.

That said, this regex will match only the second quoted string in the captured group:

```
"[^"]+"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)(?=")
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aRr1Tm/1/)

If you are certain that you will not have *any* other kind of string and that the string will terminate immediately after the final quotation mark, then [trincot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55659074/2057919) is simpler and better.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
echo '"foo":"bar"' | awk -F':' '{gsub(/"/, "", $2); print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find easy to remember this pattern by using [`\K` (Keep text out of the regex match)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html):

```
\s"\K.+(?=")
```

It can be read as:

- Ignore everything to the left before space and " `\s"\K` (remove  `"foo": "`)
- Then get everything until the first `"`  found `.+(?=")`, so ti will return just `bar`

The problem with this approach is that you always need to have the same input/pattern of items if you have something bigger won't work, for example:

```
"bla": "foo": "bar"
```

Will return:

```
foo": "bar
```

@trincot answer `[^"]*(?="$)` guarantees to always get the last item enclosed in `""`, so you could have `"bla": "foo": "bar"` and always get `bar`

@ed-cottrell answers `"[^"]+"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)(?=")` will get the second no matter the lengh

However, to just get groups you could use:

```
"([^"]*)"
```

and then with your programming of choice get the desired group